# Trying to extract an element attribute value that is part of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have an input field coded as the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="03794" class=" js-sourcing-option" data-sourcingoption="{"hasBackOrder":true,"isPartial":false,"unsourcedQty":0,"warehouseSequences":[1],"shipments":{"2017-10-12T17:00:00":{"warehouseNumber":101,"deliverByTime":"2017-10-12T17:00:00","numShipments":0,"warehouseQty":0,"backorderQty":1,"qtyByWarehouseInStock":{},"qtyByWarehouseBackorder":{"101":1}}},"sourcedQty":1,"shouldDisplay":true}">
```

Using jQuery, I cannot figure out how to get the value of "deliverByTime" (which should equal "2017-10-12T17:00:00") buried deep within the "data-sourcingoption" attribute of this field.

Using the following outputs the "name" attribute (the "[0]" is there below because there are more of these on the page):

```
$('input.js-sourcing-option')[0]["name"]
// Output: 03794
```

But if I do a similar thing for "data-sourcingoption" to try and play with the results and extract what I need, I get this:

```
$('input.js-sourcing-option')[0]["data-sourcingoption"]
// Output: undefined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...thank you!

Comment: I think you're looking for chainging the .attr() method `.attr("data-sourcingoption")`

Comment: Your html is invalid.

Comment: ^ change your outer " on your data option to be single quotes instead so the double quotes in the json do not cause it to terminate unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

`data-sourcingoption`- invalid property value.
Add hidden div with json string, and get `.html()` value if nided.

```js
         $('input:radio[name=03794]').change(function () {
          var radio_val=$(this).val();
          var json_str=$('#div_for_03794_'+radio_val).html();
          var jsonobj = JSON.parse(json_str);
          console.log(jsonobj);
         })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="radio" name="03794" class=" js-sourcing-option" value="1">
   <div id="div_for_03794_1" style="display:none;">
       {"hasBackOrder":true,"isPartial":false,"unsourcedQty":0,"warehouseSequences":[1],"shipments":{"2017-10-12T17:00:00":{"warehouseNumber":101,"deliverByTime":"2017-10-12T17:00:00","numShipments":0,"warehouseQty":0,"backorderQty":1,"qtyByWarehouseInStock":{},"qtyByWarehouseBackorder":{"101":1}}},"sourcedQty":1,"shouldDisplay":true}
   </div>
   
   
   
   
   
   <input type="radio" name="03794" class=" js-sourcing-option" value="2">
   <div id="div_for_03794_2" style="display:none;">
       {"hasBackOrder":false,"isPartial":true,"unsourcedQty":0,"warehouseSequences":[1],"shipments":{"2017-10-12T17:00:00":{"warehouseNumber":101,"deliverByTime":"2017-10-12T17:00:00","numShipments":0,"warehouseQty":0,"backorderQty":1,"qtyByWarehouseInStock":{},"qtyByWarehouseBackorder":{"101":1}}},"sourcedQty":1,"shouldDisplay":true}
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data attribute syntax seems invalid.

Can you change the outer quotes for the data attribute to a single quote in the following way?

```
<input type="radio" name="03794" class=" js-sourcing-option" data-sourcingoption='{"hasBackOrder":true,"isPartial":false,"unsourcedQty":0,"warehouseSequences":[1],"shipments":{"2017-10-12T17:00:00":{"warehouseNumber":101,"deliverByTime":"2017-10-12T17:00:00","numShipments":0,"warehouseQty":0,"backorderQty":1,"qtyByWarehouseInStock":{},"qtyByWarehouseBackorder":{"101":1}}},"sourcedQty":1,"shouldDisplay":true}'>
```

And to answer your question further, (i.e. to extract deliverByTime), you can just use this or the approach that you used to extract attributes:

```
console.log($('input.js-sourcing-option').data('sourcingoption').shipments['2017-10-12T17:00:00'].deliverByTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="03794" class="js-sourcing-option" data-sourcingoption="">
<script type="text/javascript">
var Obj = {'hasBackOrder':true,
'isPartial':false,
'unsourcedQty':0,
'warehouseSequences':[1],
'shipments': {
    'SomeName': {
        'warehouseNumber':101,
        'deliverByTime':'2017-10-12T17:00:00',
        'numShipments':0,
        'warehouseQty':0,
        'backorderQty':1,
        'qtyByWarehouseInStock': {}
        ,
        'qtyByWarehouseBackorder': {
            '101': 1
        }
    }
}
,
'sourcedQty':1,
'shouldDisplay':true
}
var element = $('.js-sourcing-option').attr('data-sourcingoption', Obj);
console.log(Obj.shipments.SomeName.deliverByTime);
```

I'm adding the "data-sourcingoption" attribute dinamicly with javascript 
The console.log is the output of deliverByTime

Answer (score 0):

all -

I ended up playing around and went with this route.  It worked to accommodate for potential multiple entries, etc.  I think it works out:

```
$('.js-sourcing-option').each(function() {
  var dataSourcing = $(this).data('sourcingoption');
  $.each(dataSourcing.shipments, function(date, shipment) {
    console.log(shipment.warehouseNumber, new Date(shipment.deliverByTime));
  });

});
```